# Can Autolayout solve a grid?

Tags: ios, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint, constraint-programming

I'm asking because I'm not sure I understand the limitations of the system completely. How many constants need to be there, and does there have to be a constant every "N" equations, or is the presence of a global constant enough?

To understand the question further, say I'm building a calculator (sorry I can't share more concrete info, but this is an accurate analogy, and I'll try to provide as much information as possible).

I do not want to hard-code button-sizes, I want them to size according to the space available. To do this, assume a simplified interface of 4x4 buttons. Then the layout will be as per the below grid (using matrix notation for the button positions and pseudo-VFL)

`| [0x0]-1-[0x1]-1-[0x2]-1-[0x3] |
|   |       |       |       |   |
|   1       1       1       1   |
|   |       |       |       |   |
| [1x0]-1-[1x1]-1-[1x2]-1-[1x3] |
|   |       |       |       |   |
|   1       1       1       1   |
|   |       |       |       |   |
| [2x0]-1-[2x1]-1-[2x2]-1-[2x3] |
|   |       |       |       |   |
|   1       1       1       1   |
|   |       |       |       |   |
| [3x0]-1-[3x1]-1-[3x2]-1-[3x3] |`

Additionally all buttons (except the last in each row and each column, which are set to <= to absorb any rounding errors) are constrained to be of the ***same*** width and the ***same*** height, as the cell [0x0].

An alternative arrangement (which I have also tried) to reduce the number of constraints, is that ***only the first row***, and the first column respectively, have the height constraint (== 0x0). Whereas NSLayoutFormatAlignAllTop is set on all the ***rows*** (cells 0x0, 0x1, 0x2 etc in one go), and NSLayoutFormatAlignAllRight is set on all the ***columns*** (cells 0x1, 1x1, 2x1, etc in one go).

> Now note that there are only ***two*** constants in the entire system:
>   the width and height as supplied by the superview.
>
> Now my question is, is that enough for the system to solve this system of about **55 constraints?**

(they are made up of: 27 1-pixel gap constraints as in the ASCII mockup above, 16 superview alignment constraints (note that the top and bottom row cells will hug the top and bottom of the superview as well) and 12 size constraints)

Can Autolayout (or the underlying Cassowary engine) really do this? Or am I stretching its capability? If this approach is wrong, how else should I approach this?

**Note:** When actually trying this in a project, it *sort of* works, but breaks on different Simulators (works on 5, has some issues on 6, breaks completely on 6 Plus, and so on). Naturally, there are warnings in the logs as well, with about a DOZEN constraints per error thrown by Autolayout, and so on.

Comment: every view need 4 constraints: (x,y) - origin point and (w,h) - width and height. Of course, several of them can be mentioned as 'trailing space' and other interesting things, but, view is a rectangle and it need (x,y) and (w,h). They can be replaced by equivalents

Comment: I'm tagging it with the general "constraint-programming" tag as well, since I'm interested in understanding if this capability is reasonable to expect from any linear-equation-solving engine, and understand if my expectations from Cassowary/Autolayout are set within the right context.

Comment: @gaussblurinc yes, but the question is of the order of magnitude. HOW MANY variables can you have relative to a small number of constants (2), before the system is just accidentally working? If you look at the layout in the question, it needs to solve ALL 55 equations before it can decide on position and size of ANY of the keys. At least that's the idea. Is the system SUPPOSED to handle this kind of load?? Is it even supposed to work properly in this situation?

Comment: I did this with a 3x3 grid of imageViews in a resizable OSX window. There was definitely a lot of trial and error. In some configurations the window would not let me resize it, in others I'd get tons of warnings and errors. One trick that worked for me was to set the Content Compression Resistance Priority to 10 & 10 for each imageView.

Comment: My views are currently EMPTY (simple UIViews) so I think the intrinsicContentSize and contentCompressionResistance shouldn't be a problem. But regardless, did this method allow you to eliminate ALL errors and warnings? (so your logs were completely clean?) Or did this help your UI work, but with some warnings.

Comment: Yes, auto layout can solve a grid. Look at Kenny's answer to his own question here, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25779201/ios-constraints-on-grid-of-equal-width-height-buttons-cause-positioning-and-size/25779972#25779972. But as I said in my answer, I would use a collection view to do this sort of thing.

Comment: Thanks @rdelmar. The example looks good. I'll have to parse what Kenny did to understand how it could work for me. Might take a while. Unfortunately I think a UICollectionViewFlowLayout may not work for me, since the layout eventually gets more complex and would be AS MUCH work in a collection-view as with constraints. However if I can get constraints in this kind of deeply-interconnected mesh to work, I can extrapolate to slightly more novel/complex layouts. Thanks for your tip.